# Is there a setting to remove the red dot regarding review queues?

Tags: support, review, top-bar

Ever since I hit 3k reputation on Math Stack Exchange, I have been seeing the red dot in the navbar right near the review queues button for close votes. I see it almost every time I visit the site.

I find it very annoying and have been opening it just to make it disappear. I couldn’t find any settings to disable it so I decided to ask here. Are there any settings to disable the red dot?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is no, though I'm coming up short on where it says it.

Comment: You could always do some reviews… with power comes responsibility ;)

Comment: You could log out, or view the site in incognito/private mode.

Comment: @Robert well if going this way, better use a sock account with low rep, this way the user can also perform actions, without annoying privileges.

Comment: I’m facing the same issue. lol

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no system/profile setting for this.

If you have an ad-blocker that's compatible with [AdBlock Plus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adblock_Plus#Filters)' filter syntax (I'm using uBlock), adding this rule seems to work:

```
stackexchange.com##div.s-activity-indicator__danger
```

Similarly, if you use a custom stylesheet manager, you could add

```css
div.s-activity-indicator__danger {
  display: none
}
```